# Obter resposta Json de URL

Tags: php, jquery, json, get

Pessoal estou tentando obter resposta de JSON a partir da URL abaixo: https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshotfullbyid/?id=1182.

Já tentei em Php e Jquery, e não consigo obter a resposta. Se colar o link no Browser, ele fornece a resposta, mas a partir dos códigos no meu localhost, não consigo.

Se acessar o site de formatação de resposta Json, https://jsonformatter.org/, e clicar em load data, a resposta aparece.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a formatar um código?

Comment: seria interessante colocar o que tentou fazer para podermos te ajudar

Comment: Você provavelmente não está conseguindo pois o site bloque algumas requisições e pede para confirmar que não é um robô.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Mas como será que o  https://jsonformatter.org/ consegue fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você provavelmente não está conseguindo pois o site bloqueia algumas requisições e pede para confirmar que não é um robô.

Essa proteção funciona basicamente da seguinte forma:

1. Ao entrar no site, o código verifique se a requisição possui, ou não, o *cookie* `cf_clearance` com um `token` válido, caso não tenha exibe o `reCaptcha` da Google.
2. Após o usuário confirmar que não é um robô, o servidor retorna um *cookie* com um `token`.

Já o site jsonformatter.org, provavelmente utiliza `cookies` para burlar essa proteção. No `php`, seria mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
<?php

/* Inicia a biblioteca cURL com a URL */
$ch = curl_init("https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshotfullbyid/?id=1182");

/* Informa que deseja capturar o resultado */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

/* Desabilita a verificação do certificado SSL */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

/* Informa o Cookie com o token válido para burlar a proteção */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cf_clearance=3def377bda6f9be22251eff64cb617c157011246-1518023345-604800");

/* Define o User-Agent para burlar a proteção */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36");

/* Captura a resposta */
$response = curl_exec($ch);

/* Captura os erros, caso haja */
$error = curl_error($ch);

/* Captura as informações da requisição */
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

/* Fecha a requisição e exibe o resultado */
curl_close($ch);

echo($response);
```

Comment: Perfeito, é isso mesmo! Tive que colocar as outras cookies também, separando por " ; ". Muito obrigado pela ajuda...